# ruby regex, splitting to mutiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split Ruby regex over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762183/split-ruby-regex-over-multiple-lines)

If I have a really long regex in ruby, how do I separate it into multiple lines to make it more readable?

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
      line.regexp = /^([^\ ]+) ([^\ ]+) \[(#{timestamp('%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')})?\] (#{ip_address}) ([^\ ]+) ([^\ ]+) (\w+(?:\.\w+)*) ([^\ ]+) "([^"]+)" (\d+) ([^\ ]+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"/
```

Comment: And can you post your regex here please, so that we can actually work on it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762183/split-ruby-regex-over-multiple-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three ways to make your code more readable. Use:

1. The `/x` modifier and add comments with `#`.
2. Inline comments with the `(?#comment_here)` modifier.
3. Named groups; For example: `(?<year>\d{2,4})` is useful for backreferencing or manipulating values afterwards.

More information:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `/x` modifier, which denotes free-spacing mode. More on that here http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the use of `/x` mentioned in the other answers, creating the regex in pieces, then gradually combining them allows you to start with small, atomic-sized pieces, then slowly grow the regex. You'll see this done with some huge patterns, such as those used to parse email addresses, internet URLs, etc.

For instance, this is from Ruby's OpenURI source code:

```
RE_LWS = /[\r\n\t ]+/n
RE_TOKEN = %r{[^\x00- ()<>@,;:\\"/\[\]?={}\x7f]+}n
RE_QUOTED_STRING = %r{"(?:[\r\n\t !#-\[\]-~\x80-\xff]|\\[\x00-\x7f])*"}n
RE_PARAMETERS = %r{(?:;#{RE_LWS}?#{RE_TOKEN}#{RE_LWS}?=#{RE_LWS}?(?:#{RE_TOKEN}|#{RE_QUOTED_STRING})#{RE_LWS}?)*}n
```

`RE_PARAMETERS` resolves to:

```
/(?:;(?-mix:[\r\n\t ]+)?(?-mix:[^\x00- ()<>@,;:\\"\/\[\]?={}\x7f]+)(?-mix:[\r\n\t ]+)?=(?-mix:[\r\n\t ]+)?(?:(?-mix:[^\x00- ()<>@,;:\\"\/\[\]?={}\x7f]+)|(?-mix:"(?:[\r\n\t !#-\[\]-~\x80-\xff]|\\[\x00-\x7f])*"))(?-mix:[\r\n\t ]+)?)*/n
```